# IIS 7.5 Invalid authentication headers 401.2 when viewing site in browser

Tags: visual-studio-2010, asp.net-mvc-2, iis-7.5

I have a Visual Studio 2010 project that is using Forms Authentiation.  It runs fine from within Cassini (visual studio systray IIS, aka pressing F5).  I'm using MVC2.

1. I created a website in IIS 7.5 (on my Windows 7 machine)
2. then pointed the physical directory at my Visual Studio project file
3. Enabled only Forms Authentication in IIS

Keep receiving this error:

HTTP Error 401.2 - Unauthorized
You are not authorized to view this page due to invalid authentication headers.

PS:  I didn't use the Create Virtual Directory option in Visual studio, since I need host headers for what i'm doing, so a dedicated IIS website.

Comment: Hi, i know this topic is old but did you manage to correct your issue? I am having the same issue in IIS 10 and no success on fixing it. I have even tryed to use the demo project from http://www.asp.net/web-forms/overview/older-versions-security/introduction/an-overview-of-forms-authentication-cs without any success.

Answer (score 9):

Follow the steps in this link

[Error message when you try to visit a Web page that is hosted on IIS 7.0: "HTTP Error 401.2 - Unauthorized"](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/942043/)

It is meant for IIS 7.0, but works for IIS 7.5 too.

Comment: These instructions don't apply to IIS 7.5, or at least the steps to fix are markedly different.

Comment: Well I managed to get what steps should be done in IIS 7.5 however doing those did not work for me, I am still getting the same error.

Comment: The link is fine.

Comment: That link is a 404.

Answer (score 0):

See if this helps.

[Fix 401.1 Error with Integrated Authentication on local machine](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/896861)